# Filtering JSON in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, filtering

I'm loading some JSON data using FETCH. I'm trying to add/create a simple filtering functionality on the content displayed.

I'm getting this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined**

Any idea what could be causing this error?

This my code so far:

```
let Table = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return { 
            accounts: [{
                "product": "Fixed Saver", 
                "interestRate": 2.20,
                "minimumDeposit": 500,
                "interestType": "Fixed"
            }],
            searchString: ''
        }
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        fetch('http://localhost:8888/table/json/accounts.json')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(json => {
                this.setState({accounts: json})
            });
    },
    handleChange: function(e){
        this.setState({searchString:e.target.value});
    },
    render: function(){
        var libraries,
        libraries = this.state.accounts,
        searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

        if(searchString.length > 0){
            libraries = libraries.filter(l => {
                return l.name.toLowerCase().match( searchString );
            });
        }

        return (
            <div className="container">

            <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type here" />

                <ul className="header clearfix">
                    <li>Product</li>
                    <li>Interest rate</li>
                    <li>Minimum deposit</li>
                    <li>Interest type</li>
                </ul>

                {libraries.map(l => {
                return (
                    <div className="account clearfix" key={l.id}>
                        <div className="product">{l.product}</div>
                        <div>{l.interestRate} %</div>
                        <div>£ {l.minimumDeposit}</div>
                        <div>{l.interestType}</div>
                    </div>
                    )
                })} 
            </div>
        )
    }
});

let App = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return(
            <Table />
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('table') );
```

**JSON**

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "product": "Fixed Saver", 
      "interestRate": 2.20,
      "minimumDeposit": 500,
      "interestType": "Fixed"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "product": "Fixed Saver", 
      "interestRate": 1.50,
      "minimumDeposit": 0,
      "interestType": "Tracker"
   },
   {
      "id": 3,
      "product": "Offset Saver", 
      "interestRate": 1.8,
      "minimumDeposit": 1000,
      "interestType": "Fixed"
   }
]
```

Comment: can you verify accounts get populated in console?My guess is your `fetch` doesn't bind to the component itself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seem that you got the error from this line

```
libraries = libraries.filter(l => {
  return l.name.toLowerCase().match( searchString );
});
```

Because of l.name is undefined. You can check again your JSON data. It doesn't have name attribute, seem that it is **product**.

You should not modify your state directly by: libraries = libraries.filter...
State should be updated by setState function.
In this case you should create temporary variable to display the results instead of directly use libraries variable.
I believe if your sample is worked, you only may search for the first time and next time the results will be only in your last search results, though.

Comment: Hi Hieu, you are right it should be product. Thanks a lot.